# set NewStyle doesn't work

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA in MS Project 2003 and working with a Word Document I try to create a new style using

```
Function CreateStyleHeadingTask(NameStyle As String) As Style
    Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = Nothing
    If Not wdDoc Is Nothing Then
        With wdDoc
            Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = .Styles.Add(Name:=NameStyle, Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph)
            '//.Styles.Add Name:=NameStyle, Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
            With .Styles(NameStyle).Font
                .Size = 14
                .Bold = True
                '//.Color = wdColorBlue
                .Color = wdColorRed
            End With
            Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = .Styles(NameStyle)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

This will crash as soon as I execute the Set CreateStyleHeadingTask statement.
If I remove the 'Set CreateStyleheadingTask =' it doesn't crash.
What is wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of the function return datatype. You need to specify Word.Style, not just Style.

```
Function CreateStyleHeadingTask(NameStyle As String) As Word.Style

    Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = Nothing

    If Not wdDoc Is Nothing Then
        With wdDoc
            Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = .Styles.Add(Name:=NameStyle, Type:=1)
            With .Styles(NameStyle).Font
                .Size = 14
                .Bold = True
                .Color = wdColorRed
            End With
            Set CreateStyleHeadingTask = .Styles(NameStyle)
        End With
    End If

End Function
```